# Uniqueness of dimensions of irreps of $S_n$

Tags: representation-theory, symmetric-groups

rather basic question here that's coming up out of curiosity, motivated by understanding the restriction and induction functors in full detail for the alternating subgroup of the symmetric group.

My question is the following: if two representations of $S_n$ restrict to the same representation of $A_n$, does it follow that each equals the tensor of the other one by the alternating representation? My first thought is that, a fortiori, does anybody know if two tableau having the same product of hook lengths, implies that the tableaux are conjugate? (Of course then hook length formula implies my hypothesis can be weakened to saying any two irreducibles of the same dimension of $S_n$).

Edit: I've found that my stronger guess about dimensions is resoundingly false: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123690/dimension-of-specht-modules-s-lambda

Comment: Do you assume that they are irreducible, resp that their restriction to $A_n$ is irreducible? Otherwise I don't think you can claim much.

Comment: Assuming they are irreducible on $S_n$, not $A_n$. Assuming my working through the exercises in Fulton & Harris's great book is correct, I'm aware that the restriction either remains irreducible or splits into two, depending as whether or not its character achieves a nonzero value on some conjugacy class of odd permutations.